# why is triangle inequality still needed to prove completeness in $l^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I read from the usual proofs that show that $l$ spaces, i.e. $l^{\infty}$, $l^1$, $l^2$ are complete - use these steps:

1) define a Cauchy sequence $\textbf{x}_n$

2) show that the pointwise limit of $\textbf{x}_n$, i.e. $\textbf{x}$, is in $l$

3) use the triangle inequality and the distance function to show that $\textbf{x}_n \rightarrow \textbf{x}$

Part (2) is usually done by using the boundedness of a Cauchy sequence, i.e. since all Cauchy sequences are bounded, it follows that the pointwise limit $\textbf{x}$ is finite, so that $\textbf{x} \in l$...

But am not sure why (3) is still needed... isn't it true that all Cauchy sequences are bound to converge to its limit? since we already showed that the limit $\textbf{x}$ is in $l$ (using step 2), why do we still need the triangle inequality to show that $\textbf{x}_n$ converges to $\textbf{x}$ (since we already assumed that it is Cauchy at the beginning)...

Comment: Because the pointwise limit is not the same as the norm limit. E.g., in $\ell_1$, the standard unit vectors (the sequence $(e_n)$ where $e_n$ is $1$ in the $n$'th coordinate and $0$ in the others) converge to $0$ pointwise, but they all have norm $1$.

Comment: thanks, but am confused, for a Cauchy sequence, there should be a $N$ s.t. elements have to be close to each other for any $\epsilon > 0$... since we assumed that the starting sequence is Cauchy, shouldn't this hold by default ? ( i.e. since the norm is always 1, the standard unit vectors may not qualify as Cauchy in $l_1$ and are not part of the proof's assumption)

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "convergence pointwise is, in general, different from convergence in norm". Here, you have to show $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ in the given norm. It is true that a Cauchy sequence in one of these spaces converges to its pointwise limit; but that requires proof (which is what you're doing for 3.).

Comment: thanks, does this mean that in sequence spaces $l$, the Cauchy criterion should be applied element-wise? i.e. for a sequence $\textbf{x}_n = (x_{n1},x_{n2},x_{n3},...)$, we have $x_{n1} \rightarrow x_1$, $x_{n2} \rightarrow x_2$ in the given norm, i.e $||x_{n1} - x_1|| \rightarrow 0$, $||x_{n2} - x_2|| \rightarrow 0$ to say that $\textbf{x}_n$ is Cauchy? (as opposed to applying the norm for the whole sequence $||\textbf{x}_n||$)

Comment: When you say "Cauchy" it's always with respect to a given norm (or metric). Given a sequence in $\ell_1$, say, you can speak of it being Cauchy *in $\ell_1$*. A sequence obtained by fixing a coordinate might be Cauchy *with respect to the usual metric on $\Bbb R$*; it makes no sense to say such a coordinate sequence in Cauchy w.r.t. the $\ell_1$- norm, since this is a sequence in $\Bbb R$ now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the result is true so its a little hard to see what could go wrong. In broad strokes, the proof says, "look for convergence in a weaker topology" (convergence in $\ell^1$ implies componentwise convergence but not vice versa), and then "upgrade this to convergence in $\ell^1$".

In a possible failed attempt of the proof, it could be that you chose such a weak topology that limits are not unique. For example, say that $x_n$ "Obviously" converges to $x$ if the first component of $x_n$ converges to the first component of $x$, $x_n(1) \to x(1)$. Then, trying to go through the proof scheme:

1. Take $x_n$ Cauchy in $\ell^1$.
2. Note that $x_n$ "Obviously" converges to $x:=(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n(1) , 0,0,0,\dots)$.
3. Conclude that $x_n$ converges to $x$ in $\ell^1$...??

So part of the reason it works is because the proof uses pointwise instead of some other badly chosen convergence. In more general spaces, its plausible that the correct weaker notion of convergence is not easy to find, and before you have the proof, its not obvious what to use. Hence you should check (however trivial) that pointwise convergence of the Cauchy sequence does in fact imply $\ell^1$ convergence.

Comment: just to ask, in $l$, a Cauchy sequence has $||\textbf{x}_n-\textbf{x}_m|| < \epsilon$ for $n,m > N$ for any $\epsilon > 0$... However, there are sequences (i.e. the typewriter sequence) which converges in the norm but not pointwise --- are these sequences still Cauchy ?

Comment: @LinkL that's a sequence of functions, right? so not in an $\ell^p$ space, rather $L^p([0,1])$. Whether or not they are Cauchy depends heavily on the mode of convergence; they aren't pointwise Cauchy, they are Cauchy in $L^1$